# Calling invalidate on a gridview changes the color of EditText's to white

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm drawing the grid view in my activity like this:

```
AlbumGridAdapter albumAdapter = new AlbumGridAdapter(this);
GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
gv.setAdapter(albumAdapter);
```

Then when I need to refresh the view (after some user input in a dialog):

```
gv.setAdapter(new AlbumGridAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
gv.invalidate();
```

After this is called, my EditTexts (below) become white. Other than that the "refresh" is working.

This is the xml for the grid:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$DummySectionFragment" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/label"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:gravity="center" 
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:textIsSelectable="false" />

<GridView
android:id="@+id/grid"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
android:gravity="center" >
</GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the xml for each grid cell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_cell"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/no_image"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/caption"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using your Activity instead of your Application as the Context you give to your Adapter. I'm guessing that because you are using `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"`, which refers to a theme attribute, you are getting your Application's theme, which may not be the same as your Activity theme.